# How to transform a container of string slices in Rust?

Tags: rust

Suppose I have a `Vec<&str>` (I have no control over this type) and I need to transform  each string. Since the elements are string slices (which don't own the string), I need to store the actual strings **somewhere**.

I thought about storing the new strings in a container that's able to grow without reallocating. So I came up with the following:

```rs
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn transform(s: &str) -> String {
    s.to_owned() + "blah"
}

pub fn func<'a>(strings: &mut Vec<&'a str>, string_storage: &'a mut VecDeque<String>) {
    for string in strings.iter_mut() {
        string_storage.push_back(transform(string));
        *string = string_storage.back().unwrap().as_str();
    }
}
```

Of course, it doesn't work (I get `` error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*string_storage` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable ``). I understand why the error happens, but I've struggled for some time to figure out a solution.

The best I could come up with is to separate the pushes and assignments into two loops:

```rs
pub fn func<'a>(strings: &mut Vec<&'a str>, string_storage: &'a mut Vec<String>) {
    for string in strings.iter() {
        string_storage.push(transform(string));
    }
    for (i, string) in strings.iter_mut().enumerate() {
        *string = string_storage[i].as_str();
    }
}
```

But it seems weird to have to iterate twice. Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: "a container that's able to grow without reallocating" I'm not quite sure what your intention with that part is, but I can assure you that a `VecDeque` will reallocate if you grow it past its capacity.

Comment: Is it crucial that the original `Vec<&str>` is mutated in place? If so, where does that requirement come from?

Comment: Iterating twice lets you promise at compile time that you won't delete any of the strings out from under their references, by promising you won't mutate the container. Otherwise, how would that promise be expressed, that you might add new ones but won't delete? It shouldn't make a significant performance difference. But your two-loop version is assuming it was passed an empty `VecDeque`; you should fix that.

Comment: @SvenMarnach 1: Well, I assumed it wouldn't reallocate the contiguous sections (like C++'s `std::deque`) but I think you're right and that may not be the case. 2: This is a simplified version of the problem I faced when trying to transform the strings contained in [freedesktop_desktop_entry::Group](https://docs.rs/freedesktop-desktop-entry/latest/freedesktop_desktop_entry/type.Groups.html), which uses `&str` instead of `String` (for some reason), only instead of `Groups` it's a simple `Vec<&str>`. The reason I need to mutate in place is that I need to save the modified `DesktopEntry`.

Comment: @DanGetz 1: What if I had an append-only container where references to its elements are always valid? 2: TBH, I'm not really worried about performance, since the function is not time-sensitive, in this case I mostly care about readability/cleanliness. 3: Good catch. Thanks.

Comment: The `freedesktop_desktop_entry` seems to be exclusively intended for parsing desktop entry files, and not for modifying or writing them. Are you relying on the `Display` trait to write the file back? It doesn't seem to be intended for that purpose either, so I think you are better off writing your own code to write the file.

Comment: @SvenMarnach You're right. It seems I can't even use the `freedesktop_desktop_entry` crate for parsing, because it seems to just ignore comments, and the [spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#basic-format:~:text=they%20should%20be%20preserved%20across%20reads%20and%20writes%20of%20the%20desktop%20entry%20file) requires comments to be preserved. I'll look for another crate or write something myself. I'm still curious about the original question, though.

Comment: @LHLaurini Your best option for the original question would be creating vectors with the new strings and then a new instance of `DesktopEntry` referencing the new strings. Changing the old instance in place is too awkward.